# How to merge two folder tree

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to merge folder tree "lhsTree" to folder tree "rhsTree"

if any folder is missing on rhsTree I have to add it from lshTree by caomparing them. what would be the best/easy way to do it?

here is what I did so far

```
    for(let i = 0;  i < rhsTree.length; i++){
if (previewItem.label == treedataItem.label) {
              treedataItem.children.forEach((child) => {
              child.wstype = "previewfoldernoid";
              previewItem.children.push(child);
            });
            previewItem.wstype = FOLDER_ICON_TYPE.plainFolder; 
            previewItem.applyState = FOLDER_APPLY_STATE.reddot;
          }
        }
```

this way I can update the folder icon of the parent element. I need to update the foldericon on the child level as well

[image]

output json

```
[{"id":"WorkA!55","templateId":"","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"nan","wstype":"workspace","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[{"id":"WorkA!96","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!55","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"no repeat","wstype":"previewfolderid","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[{"id":"WORKA!97","templateId":"28ce7c14-c6ba-ec52-2093-52f9f375d53b","parent_id":"WORKA!96","label":"first repeatADMIN","wstype":"previewfolderid","folder_type":"regular","status":1,"expanded":true,"children":[{"id":"WORKA!98","templateId":"6d5f670f-656c-0af3-8f05-20541db1cf75","parent_id":"WORKA!97","label":"second repeat [Owner]","wstype":"folder","status":1,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":1},{"id":"6d5f670f-656c-0af3-8f05-20541db1cf75","label":"second repeat USER1","expanded":true,"collapsedIcon":"fa fa-folder","checkbox":true,"templateState":0,"children":[{"id":"5d9f02ec-5d71-c525-7104-1b0f887168e3","label":"New folder 1","expanded":true,"collapsedIcon":"fa fa-folder","checkbox":true,"templateState":0,"children":[],"wstype":"previewfoldernoid"}],"wstype":"previewfoldernoid"}],"total":0,"applyState":0},{"id":"WORKA!103","templateId":"28ce7c14-c6ba-ec52-2093-52f9f375d53b","parent_id":"WORKA!96","label":"first repeat","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":1,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":1},{"id":"WORKA!104","templateId":"28ce7c14-c6ba-ec52-2093-52f9f375d53b","parent_id":"WORKA!96","label":"first repeatTEST01","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":1,"expanded":true,"children":[{"id":"WORKA!105","templateId":"6d5f670f-656c-0af3-8f05-20541db1cf75","parent_id":"WORKA!104","label":"second repeat [Owner]","wstype":"folder","status":1,"expanded":true,"children":[{"id":"WORKA!106","templateId":"5d9f02ec-5d71-c525-7104-1b0f887168e3","parent_id":"WORKA!105","label":"New folder 1","wstype":"folder","status":1,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":1}],"total":0,"applyState":1}],"total":0,"applyState":1},{"id":"WorkA!99","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!96","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"twest","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":3}],"total":4,"applyState":0},{"id":"WorkA!76","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!55","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"New folder 1","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":3},{"id":"WorkA!78","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!55","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"New folder 2","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":3},{"id":"WorkA!77","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!55","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"New folder 3","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":3},{"id":"WorkA!69","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!55","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"new test","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":3},{"id":"WorkA!70","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!55","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"new1","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":3},{"id":"WorkA!71","templateId":"","parent_id":"WorkA!55","workspace_id":"WorkA!55","label":"new2","wstype":"folder","folder_type":"regular","status":3,"expanded":true,"children":[],"total":0,"applyState":3}],"total":7,"applyState":3}]
```

Comment: Please show your data structures and expected output.

Comment: added screen shot of the folder tree. while merging I need to add anything that is missed out on rhsTree. Including child

Comment: Sorry, that's really complex and you're essentially asking me to type that all in so that I can make a [mcve] that I'm able to run and work with. It's in browser-specific syntax so it's totally unclear what much of this information is, even if I had the patience to type it all in by hand. Please see [why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) and provide a complete working example with just enough information to show the problem. Thanks!

Comment: updated my question with json output. can you please take a quick look